# NUnit tests not showing up in Visual Studio test explorer

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, tdd, nunit

I'm doing a simple little exercise but its kinda outside my current experience. I'm quite new to both visual studios and Nunits, basically I have created a simple database and a class to insert/delete/update it written in C# and what Im struggling to do is get NUnits to work for me to test the methods I have written.

I have installed NUnit 3.0 and the NUnit adaptor through NuGet and have opened a new project and added referin my solution with a class library in which I have written my tests, here's where I got a bit lost. The tests I have written do not show up in test explorer and I have tried every source I can find to explain why with no success, I have changed the processor architecture setting between x86 and x64 and cleaned and rebuilt etc but nothing. Any help or tips would be much appreciated and Thank you very much in advance.

These are the methods

```
namespace Employees
{

    public class DatabaseConnection
    {
        private string connectionString="bla blah blah";    
        SqlConnection connection;

        public string read()
        {
            string query = "SELECT LAST(first_name) FROM Employee";
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) //Reperesents a set of data commands and a database connection
            {
                connection.Open();
                string name = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return name;
            }
        }

        public void insertEntry(string first_name,string last_name, string title, string dept)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ('@first_name','@last_name','@job_title','@department')";
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) //Reperesents a set of data commands and a database connection
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", first_name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", last_name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_title", title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", dept);

                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        public void updateEntry(int id, string first_name, string last_name, string title, string dept)
        {
            string query = "UPDATE Employees SET first_name='@first_name', last_name='@last_name', job_title='@job_title', department='@department' WHERE id = '@Employeeid";
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) //Reperesents a set of data commands and a database connection
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", first_name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", last_name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_title", title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", dept);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employeeid", id);

                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        public void deleteEntry(int id)
        {
            string query = "DELETE FROM Employees WHERE id = @Employeeid";
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) //Reperesents a set of data commands and a database connection
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employeeid", id);

                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample test cases I had planned to use:

```
namespace TestLib.NUnitTest
{

    using NUnit.Framework;

    using Employees;

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void insertSuccess()
        {
            string a = "Levi";
            string b = "Smith";
            string c = "Sales Assistant";
            string d = "Sales";
            DatabaseConnection con = new DatabaseConnection();
            con.insertEntry(a, b, c, d);
            string n = con.read();
            Assert.AreEqual(a, n);
        }

        [Test]
        public void insertFail()
        {
            string a = "Levi";
            string b = "Smith";
            string c = "Sales Assistant";
            string d = "Sales";
            DatabaseConnection con = new DatabaseConnection();
            con.insertEntry(a, b, c, d);
            string n = con.read();
            Assert.AreEqual(a, n);
        }

        [Test]
        public void updateSuccess()
        {
            Assert.Pass("This is a pass");

            //DatabaseConnection con = new DatabaseConnection();
            //Assert.That(con.insertEntry(a, b, c, d));
        }

        [Test]
        public void updateFail()
        {
            if (true)
                Assert.Fail("This is a failure");

        }


        [Test]
        public void deleteSuccess()
        {
            Assert.Pass("This is a pass");

            //DatabaseConnection con = new DatabaseConnection();
            //Assert.That(con.insertEntry(a, b, c, d));
        }

        [Test]
        public void deleteFail()
        {
            if (true)
                Assert.Fail("This is a failure");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is the full source and project available somewhere in the public domain?

Comment: No sorry, its a task I was set for an internship. I've done as much as I could with all this being new to me but I've been stuck at this point for a while now and need a push in the right direction

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?  Also are you using the NUnit3.0 Test Adapter?  Last question, what architecture are your tests set for (x86 or x64)?

Comment: @Dresden Visual studios 2013, Yes I installed NUnit 3.0 and the NUnit adapter along with it from NuGet and its set to x86 architecture.

Comment: I would suggest that you start by running the tests on the command line using nunit3-console. That will determine if there is a problem with your test assembly, or with the Visual Studio Adapter.

Comment: You also said NUnit Adapter several times. Make sure you have the NUnit 3 adapter installed. If you could post output from the test output window, it might also provide clues.

Comment: To be clear... NUnit Adapter and NUnit 3 Adapter are two different programs and two different nuget packages.

Comment: @RobProuse I think that might be the problem, the exact names of what I have installed are "NUnit 3" version 3.2.1 and "NUnit Test Adaptor for VS 12/13/15" when I search NuGet there is no mention of an NUnit 3 Adaptor tho?

Comment: Thanks so much, I found the correct adapter and the tests showed up. I appreciate your help very much and if you have spotted any other errors or silly things I might have done in the code or wherever I would love some constructive criticism. Thank again